# Want to build URL after parsing using python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to replace a parameter value from the URL using the following code. After replacing the value of parameter I get the following data in variable **query_dict**

```
{
    'part': ['snippet,replies'],
    'allThreadsRelatedToChannelId': ['UCBqUbOUyAsTB7Xc7xQAHWZA'],
    'maxResults': ['100'],
    'pageToken': 'QURTSl9pMGhfWTZoU3dPX2dNendrSUZqRU1IVk5mTmVvVkpxT2c3dkJBbzdNME80SldsWnY0dHFYck9raUpxT0dqRm9pZ2k4Smo1Q2ZKSE5NWmZLWEVkcm5acC1paU9HUFpUaTlKdVljYjFqOUx5YzVVQzA4bmlSYkVxOGNISDVWY0E2ZmVuMVN5TFB6bWx2MGc=',
    'key': my_key
}
```

When I try to build url using unparse method it gives the following error

> not enough values to unpack (expected 7, got 6).

What's wrong? Following is the current code

```
r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
a=r.read().decode('utf-8')
data =json.loads(a)
parts = urlparse(url)
query_dict = parse_qs(parts.query) 
query_dict['pageToken'] = data['nextPageToken']
build_url=urllib.parse.urlunparse(query_dict)
```

Comment: [`urlunparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlunparse) takes a six-item iterable as argument. You are passing a dictionary.

Comment: I note that the sample `query_dict` you include in your question has no `nextPageToken` key, so you'd get a key error there. The dictionary also has 5 keys, not 6, so your exception would state that it `(expected 7, got 5)`.

Answer (score 7):

`urlunparse()` is the inverse of the [`urllib.parse.urlparse()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) and deals with completely different information. It is not the function to use to create a new query string from your dictionary.

The proper inverse is the [`urllib.parse.urlencode()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode), use that instead, with the `doseq` parameter set to `True` to handle the lists returned by `urlparse()`. See the [`urlparse()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs):

> Use the `urllib.parse.urlencode()` function (with the `doseq` parameter set to `True`) to convert such dictionaries into query strings.

You can then pass the resulting string back to `urlunparse` (together with the other `parts` minus the query string), or use the [namedtuple `_replace()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace) to create an updated [URL parse result object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#structured-parse-results), which has a [`.geturl()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urllib.parse.SplitResult.geturl):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs, urlencode

parts = urlparse(url)
query_dict = parse_qs(parts.query) 
query_dict['pageToken'] = data['nextPageToken']
build_url = parts._replace(query=urlencode(query_dict, doseq=True)).geturl()
```

Demo:

```py
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs, urlencode
>>> url = "http://example.com/foo/bar?part=snippet%2Creplies&allThreadsRelatedToChannelId=UCBqUbOUyAsTB7Xc7xQAHWZA&maxResults=100&pageToken=QURTSl9pMGhfWTZoU3dPX2dNendrSUZqRU1IVk5mTmVvVkpxT2c3dkJBbzdNME80SldsWnY0dHFYck9raUpxT0dqRm9pZ2k4Smo1Q2ZKSE5NWmZLWEVkcm5acC1paU9HUFpUaTlKdVljYjFqOUx5YzVVQzA4bmlSYkVxOGNISDVWY0E2ZmVuMVN5TFB6bWx2MGc%3D&key=%3Cexample+key+value%3E"
>>> data = {"nextPageToken": "<example next page token>"}
>>> parts = urlparse(url)
>>> query_dict = parse_qs(parts.query)
>>> query_dict['pageToken'] = data['nextPageToken']
>>> print(parts._replace(query=urlencode(query_dict, doseq=True)).geturl())
http://example.com/foo/bar?part=snippet%2Creplies&allThreadsRelatedToChannelId=UCBqUbOUyAsTB7Xc7xQAHWZA&maxResults=100&pageToken=%3Cexample+next+page+token%3E&key=%3Cexample+key+value%3E
```

Comment: great help @Martijn. I tried this but the resultant URL is not properly build I have the following URL url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet%2Creplies&allThreadsRelatedToChannelId=UCBqUbOUyAsTB7Xc7xQAHWZA&maxResults=100&pageToken=QURTSl9pMmtEczg4MHVORVFQMXB5RVg2Q1Qxd1BLak9zQ1JjNDBpUWJfZ2NhdWV5R3pId0ZZbkFVcXhGSTdUc3d6bERrRk9nOU1vZnBTZGl5VV9kWm8wdjVfUmZGeWNsWTBnMy16My03ZXZfcWdKcWlRbmRJRG5lQUdLQlBjUXJPYTA%3D&key=mykey";

Comment: @anil: anything wrong in that URL will have resulted from the *inputs*, not the code in my answer.

Comment: anil: not that I can tell what might be wrong with it, because I don't have the original input string either. Please use backticks (`\``) around strings you want to communicate as literals.

Comment: `url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet%2Creplies&allThreadsRelatedToChannelId=UCBqUbOUyAsTB7Xc7xQAHWZA&maxResults=100&pageToken=QURTSl9pMmtEczg4MHVORVFQMXB5RVg2Q1Qxd1BLak9zQ1JjNDBpUWJfZ2NhdWV5R3pId0ZZbkFVcXhGSTdUc3d6bERrRk9nOU1vZnBTZGl5VV9kWm8wdjVfUmZGeWNsWTBnMy16My03ZXZfcWdKcWlRbmRJRG5lQUdLQlBjUXJPYTA%3D&key=AIzaSyCNveCCr3exzqIZDUHhqgFVF3ujuy5plgA";
`

Comment: @anil: you *could* make matters much easier by using a dummy URL instead and explaining how that is not giving you the correct result. Such as `url = 'http://example.org/foo?part=bar&key=spam'`, and go from there. That leaves out a whole lot of text that we *don't need here* to diagnose your issue.

Comment: I think the final line above
`build_url = parts._replace(query=urlencode(query_dict), True).geturl()`

should have the `True` parameter inside the `urlencode` function
instead of being passed to the `_replace` function

`build_url = parts._replace(query=urlencode(query_dict, True)).geturl()`

doesn't it?

Comment: @JREnriquez: good catch, yes, that's a typo on my part!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [furl](https://github.com/gruns/furl).

```
from furl import furl

url = furl("http://example.org/foo?part=bar&key=spam")
url.set({"part": "foo"})
url.url
```